# What is MaxSNP - Complete

Tags: complexity-theory, approximation

I am trying to understand what is MaxSNP-complete. I have read the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNP_(complexity)) definition. I would like to get the intuition behind it. My knowledge of computational complexity is very basic.

Comment: Have you tried reading the original paper defining this class?

Comment: No. I haven't thought of reading it. You mean the paper of Papadimitriou?

Comment: Yes. It's a somewhat older paper, so they might actually take the trouble to explain their ideas.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try. Thanks! As far as I understand a problem in MaxSNP class implies that the problem can not have an PTAS, right? Is there any relation with apx hardness?

Comment: Quoting Wikipedia: "There is a fixed-ratio approximation algorithm to solve any problem in MaxSNP."